# Android layout-sw340dp issue for htc evo 3d

Tags: android

I need to create layouts for htc evo 3D phone, i created them but its automatically gets the layout-normal and it does not fits for the phone, so then i created new layout as layout-sw340dp and set of images as dreawble-sw340dp its displays compatible fine in the eclips layout designer, but when i check it in the emulator, its displaying the same layout-normal layouts, can any one help me with this...
Application API level is 2.3.3

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Comment: doing the half of the screen, shouldn't it be sw270dp, as for GS3 we do sw360dp, half of 720

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android 2.3.3 emulator is only works for basic three layouts eg:- layout-large, layout-normal, layout-small, but layouts in layout-sw340dp folder works perfectly in avd instance in 4.0.1